# How to update changed on GitHub from PyCharm

Tags: python, github, pycharm

So I am new to GitHub and decided to add my project there (https://github.com/MiniMinnoww/moviepy-video-editor)

Now I have edited my files a bit in my PyCharm editor, and now I want to update the files on GitHub to match them - how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured it out! I have to click 'Git' on the menu bar, then 'current file' then 'commit' and 'commit and push'